# MVC Dynamic Google Maps Marker

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to plot multiple dynamic google maps marker from my MVC model items. I am able to do it by hard coding but not dynamically. What am I missing?

```
function codeAddress(index, value)
    {
        //var addressArray = ['Canada', 'India', 'America'];
        //$.each(addresses, function()
        //{
        //    var addresses = value.ASSET_NAME;
        //});
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            var addressArray = Model[i].ASSET_NAME;
        }

        //var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        for (var x = 0; x < addressArray.Count(); x++)
        {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressArray[x] }, function (results, status)
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location                    
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: consider this sample http://www.jmelosegui.com/map/marker/DataBindingToModel

Answer (score 0):

because of the scope, your `addressArray` lives only inside the for loop. That's why you get an error when you try to get `addressArray.Count()`;

instead, make an empty array first like this:

```
var addressArray = [];
```

and instead of overwriting the addressArray, you should you `push` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        addressArray.push(Model[i].ASSET_NAME);
    }
```

=-=-=- edit -=-=-=

My bad, somehow I thought it was pure javascript. Sadly I have no idea about asp.net, but you should build a javascript array string using asp.net, and assign it to the Javascript addressArray.
So, I think you can try something like this instead:

```
@{
var addressArray = '[';
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i!=0){
             addressArray = addressArray + ',';
        };
        addressArray = addressArray + '"' + Model[i].ASSET_NAME+ '"' ;
    };
addressArray = addressArray + ']';
}

var addressArray = @addressArray;
```

Comment: With the above code I get the error "addressArray does not exist in the current context" in the for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)

Comment: Thanks Kaho. Let me try it your way.